# c# multiple form with common items from basefrom

Tags: c#, forms

it's any way to inherit form from baseForm, f.e:

i have Baseform with menu and some button. Now I want to use it in my second form, **but i would not copy-paste**, but only:

```
   public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
```

and now i have some problems, because compilator send me bugs:

> Message   1   The designer could not be shown for this file because none
>   of the classes within it can be designed.  The designer inspected the
>   following classes in the file:
>
> dziedziczony --- The base class '_10widokow.**BaseForm**' could not be
>   loaded.  Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects
>   have been built.

Comment: Did you rebuild the project already? What you are seeing here is not a compiler error but an error in the designer. Often this is solved by rebuilding the project (in general what you are trying to do is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Those errors probably due to your `BaseForm` either not being referenced, or you have other problems outside of the scope of the question.

Controls on a form are added by the `InitialiazeComponents` method generated by the Form graphical editor. You don't **need** to inherit to bring in a basic set of controls, but simply copy the generated code out to a common location.
Then call in the constructor of the forms in which you want the base controls.